# How can I avoid this "if" block in viewDidLoad to be executed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewdidload

First sorry for not being accurate in the title, but I will try to describe my issue as precise as possible.

I am developing an app to manage costs/expenses. In this case I have this **block** in the `viewdidload` method:

**Piece of code about what I got so far:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

 if([[self getfrequencyselected] isEqualToString:@"Daily"] && [self limitneedstoberaised]){
  NSDateComponents *component = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];

        switch ([component weekday]) {
              case 1:[self raisedaylimit];
                    break;
              case 2: [self raisedaylimit];
                    break;
               --- etc,etc ---
             default:
                    break;
        }

  }
}

 -(BOOL)limitneedstoberaised{
  /*

   Something like this: 

   If today's date is the same as the date stored in the SQLite DB (LASTUPDATEDATE column), 
   then return FALSE, else return TRUE;
   [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] isDate:date1 inSameDayAsDate:date2];


  */

 }
```

- Basically if the user has previously selected to keep track of costs in a daily basis, enter in that switch case.
 - In the switch case 1, 2, etc represent the days of the week, so it should raise the specified cost limit every day that has passed.

**My problem:**

This block is in the `viewdidload`, so it will be executed every time the app is launched.

My problem is that `[self raisedaylimit]` will be, therefore, called every time the user launches the app, so I would like to avoid that, by just to be executed once per day, as the logic says.

**Possible solution:**

- I have thought about creating a NSUserDefaults object to keep track when the `raisedaylimit` method is called, toggling between YES and NO, but that seems complicated.
- I have thought that maybe this block will need to be outside of the `viewdidload` method so that the block is executed just when it's needed

Comment: "This block is in the viewdidload, so it will be executed every time the app is launched" Of course. That is what `viewDidLoad` means. Actually, what it means is, every time this view controller comes into existence and obtains its view. If that isn't when you wanted to run your code, then this was a silly place to put it. — "maybe this block will need to be outside of the viewdidload method so that the block is executed just when it's needed" Okay, so when is it needed? If you can tell us that, we can suggest where to position the code so that it runs then.

Comment: Hi matt :). Thanks for the reply. So I will tell you, basically when the user launches the app, the block checks if a daily, weekly or monthly frequency is selected. Based on this, the switch will determine in which day the limit needs to be raised. This block will NOT be executed when the limit is already raised. I am not sure if it makes better sense now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first thought is correct, you need to store the day you last raised the limit *outside* of your app - and in user defaults is the obvious place.

Your code will read the stored date, get the current date, and calculate the number of days between them – read the `NSDate` documentation, there are methods which will determine the difference between two dates to some granularity (hours, days, etc.), you do not need to reduce an `NSDate` value by stripping off the time component yourself before do the difference calculation.

Call your code on app launch. If you need to allow for your app running past midnight and needing to raise the limit a second (or third etc.) time your code should calculate the time left till midnight and set an `NSTimer` to call itself again.

If you get stuck designing your solution ask a new question with the code you have developed, what your problem is, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you at that point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) . I have discovered something. `NSCalendar` has a method called `-(BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date1 inSameDayAsDate:(NSDate *)date2 NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, 8_0)` which returns TRUE is two dates are in the same day. My code can be like this : If today and stored last updated day are in the same day, do nothing, else [self raisedaylimit]; I only need to raise the limit once per day. Do you think this can work? Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Do you think this can work?" - Ask yourself questions such as: Do you need to raise the limit once per calendar day or once per day your app is run? Do you need to raise the limit if your app executes over midnight? Nobody here can answer these questions for you. Once you have your answers devise and algorithm to handle them.